# Confusing module sql install failure

Tags: setup-script

Alright, this is pretty embarrassing. Setup scripts are supposed to be no problem, but I am having an awful time executing my install script.

**config.xml**

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Redacted_Tsc>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Redacted_Tsc>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <resources>
      <tsc_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Redacted_Tsc</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </tsc_setup>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

**mysql4-install-1.0.0.php**

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$tscRoot = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->setName('Redacted TSC')
    ->setUrlKey('tsc')
    ->setIsActive(1)
    ->setIsAnchor(0)
    ->save()
    ;
$site = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('code', 'redacted')
    ->getFirstItem()
    ;

$storeGroup = Mage::getModel('core/store_group')
    ->setWebsiteId($site->getId())
    ->setName('TSC')
    ->setRootCategoryId($tscRoot->getId())
    ->save()
    ;

$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')
    ->setWebsiteId($site->getId())
    ->setGroupId($storeGroup->getId())
    ->setName('TSC Store')
    ->setIsActive(0)
    ->save()
    ;
$installer->endSetup();
```

Couple of notes about the installer: I decided that it would be nice to have automated site/store group/store/root category creation so that I can be certain that the developed product is the same as what's in production. Figured an installer would be a handy way to go. If I'm crazy, let me know!

**Redacted_Tsc.xml**

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Redacted_Tsc>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local></codePool>
    </Redacted_Tsc>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Checklist:

- There's no entry in the `core_resource` table
- Caches are 100% off

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Semi-canonical setup resource debugging scripts here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717535/my-magento-extension-install-script-will-not-run

Comment: A) Not getting any errors. B) I attempted using your recommendations (at least the ones from the answer on StackOverflow), but somehow missed the full article. I'll give that a try, thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or is it simply not running the install script? What does your file-structure look like?

Comment: There was a typo in my etc/modules entry: `local>` when I needed `local`. It's odd, the module was showing up properly in the admin panel (under config/advanced/advanced). Benmarks' answer below is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a pretty good look at that extra `>` in your `<codePool>` text node ("local>").

Comment: oh damn :/ I hate such errors, so hard to debug :(

Comment: This one comes up regularly in the Magento U Fundamentals of Dev class - it's very, very hard to spot.

Answer (score 3):

My standard error is a missing `tsc_setup` folder inside the sql:

```
app/(local|community)/Namespace/ModuleName/sql/(setup_name)/install-1.0.0.php
```

in your case:

```
app/local/Redacted/Tsc/sql/tsc_setup/install-1.0.0.php
```

There is no need for mysql4 if you are implementing for magento 1.6+

Comment: It's good to know that `mysql4` is unnecessary. It seemed to be one of Magento's more arbitrary requirements.

Comment: long story short: in later days it was necessary, today you can have more than one install script install- for general purposes and mysql-install or pgsql-install (later maybe) to address special RDBMSs